# How to send an email every three days until booking is confirmed

Tags: php, email

I have a client who wants his application to send an email every three days to his customers that have not agreed to T&C for a booking up until the date of the booking. This will be a cron job but the problem I'm having is how to continuously check every three days for an unknown amount of time. I could just set numerous if else checks but at some stage it could/will break because I haven't put in enough checks. Each check will perform the same task of sending the email.

How can I improve the if else checks for every three days?

My script is below

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM bookings " .
    "WHERE DATE(date) > DATE(NOW()) " .
    "AND dateofquote != '' " .
    "AND email != '' " .
    "AND confirmed = 0";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
$num_rows = mysql_numrows($result);

$today = date('Y-m-d');
$count = 3;

if($num_rows){
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $date_of_quote = $row['dateofquote'];

    $datetime1 = new DateTime($today);
    $datetime2 = new DateTime($date_of_quote);
    $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
    $diff = $interval->format('%a');


 // How do I improve this process from here
    if($diff == '3'){
        // send email
    } elseif($diff == '6'){
        // send email
    } elseif($diff == '9'){
        // send email
    } else {
        echo 'something went wrong';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Modulo operator

```
6%3
```

will output 0

```
9%3
```

as well.

**In your case**

```
if($diff % 3 == 0){ 
//send email
...}
```

Comment: The modulus operator gives you the remainder.  (The remainder of 6 divided by 3.)  So you can check to see if the remainder is 0.  If it is, then the number, in this case 3, goes into 6 or 9 evenly and you know to send the email.